# ssis dynamic connection string variables

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssis, sql-server-2008-r2, bids

I am having collection SSIS packages created by someone.Example shown below
[image]

In Each and every package they created Variables.Inside my project folder I can able to find Democonnectionstring

[image]

Inside the Democonnectionstring
[image]

What my question is why they are using Variables and DemoConnectionString and if I want to change my Servername and Password where I should change.Any one explain me in detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to run your ssis package in BIDS(i.e in your development) you can change variable values in variable window according to your need then run the package. so now you can change your variables in variable window. But how you will change your variable if you have only executable dtsx package but not actual solution.

Here only configuration files comes into picture, where you can change all the dynamic variables without editing your packages. The demo password and password is something they might have created for test purpose. Try to remove one or other password and run the package, if it is working fine then remove unnecessary variables. If the variables prepend USER string then that is user defined variable. Right click your connection and go to properties window and check expression option to see any user variables assigned.

Comment: I am having 10 packages.If i want to run this package in different environment (ie) different username,password and database,whether i should edit every package to change the database or in Democonnectionstring change the values enough.

Comment: No, if you change values in config file thats enough. But all the connection strings of packages should be available in config. If not available create confile to add those as well

Answer (score 2):

Go to the control flow tab and make sure no shapes are selected. Then in the Menu bar expand "SSIS" and go to "Package Configurations"

There you will find a list of configurations which have been set up for the package. I suspect that you'll find a configuration there which uses an XML file to assign values to variables.

Comment: In that I can able to find XML configuration file.But small doubt in Configuration File they using password as afl123$%^ and in variables Demo password as testpass%^,How little bit confusing